# Elasticsearch order facets based on another index

Tags: search, indexing, elasticsearch, facet, faceted-search

I'm not sure of the right term to describe this problem so I'll go with a simple example.

I have blog posts index each with tags field (not_analyzed):

```
{
  id: 1
  tags: ['a']
},
{
  id: 2
  tags: ['a', 'b']
},
{
  id: 3
  tags: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

and if I run search for `tag:c` I successfully get 3 post results and facets on tags:

```
{
  term: 'a',
  count: 3
},
{
  term: 'b',
  count: 2
}
```

In the result above, the facets are ordered by count. My question is, if it's possible to boost their values calculated from another index? If I have another index for tags with scores (arbitrary)

```
{
  tag: 'a',
  score: 0
},
{
  tag: 'b',
  score: 10
},
{
  tag: 'c',
  score: 0
},
```

Is it possible to achieve the following facets with scores calculated from another index?

```
{
  tag: 'b'
  score: 12 //10 + 2, where 2 is the count
},
{
  tag: 'b'
  score: 3 //0 + 3, where 3 is the count
}
```

**I'm aware that facets are being deprecated and I should update my code to use aggregations.*